# Find the integer solutions of the equation $x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + x_4 = 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

Considering the equation:

$x_1 - x_2  - x_3 + x_4 = 0$

such that:

$x_i \le 1000$ and $x_i > 0$

Find the number of integer solutions. How to consider the subtractions?

Comment: Addition is easier to visualize,  we want $x_1+x_4=x_2+x_3$.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the equation as
$$x_1+x_4 = x_2+x_3$$
and suppose both sides are equal to $s$ for some $s \in [2,2000]$. If $s=2$ then there is only one possibility: $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=1$. If $s=3$, there are two possibilities for the pair $(x_1, x_4)$, namely $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$; the same goes for the pair $(x_2, x_3)$. If $s=4$, there are three possibilities for both pairs, and so on. The number of possibilities will increase up to a point (where?), and then will decrease, returning to one possibility at $s=2000$.

Thus the number of solutions is:
$$1\cdot1 + 2\cdot2 + 3\cdot3 + \dots + 2\cdot2 + 1\cdot1.$$

You will want to use the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$.